# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar una webview en xamarin si se cumple una condicion?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

¿Cómo puedo ocultar una `WebView` en **Xamarin** si se cumple una condición?. Esta `WebView` la creo en el `XML`. Soy nuevo en **Xamarin**

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinWeb" x:Class="XamarinWeb.XamarinWeb">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">

      <WebView x:Name="wvUrl" HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000" Source = "www.google.com">
      </WebView>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2):

Obtienes la referencia del `WebView` en tu xml (layout):

```
  <WebView x:Name="wvUrl" HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000" Source = "www.google.com">
      </WebView>
```

En este caso es `wvUrl` :

```
 if(condicion){
      wvUrl.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
 }
```

Comment: Disculpa es que soy nuevo en **Xamarin**, Donde iría obteniendo lo del id y la condición en el AppDelegate.cs o en el Main.cs ?

Comment: En el Main ya que en este se carga el layout que contendría el WebView.

Comment: Pero en este caso no tengo id en el xml, pondria el name o no hace falta? tal cual como esta lo dejo?

Comment: Agrego modificación a mi pregunta, es bueno siempre agregues detalles.

Comment: El visual no me reconoce el Visibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
using CallKit;
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace App5
{
    public partial class ultimoViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ultimoViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {

        }

        partial void UIButton5122_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            uiweb1a.Hidden = false;

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

               var url = "www.google.com"; // NOTE: https secure request
            uiweb1a.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
            uiweb1a.Hidden = true;
        }

        partial void UIButton5126_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            uiweb1a.Hidden = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: agrega información del por qué este código resuelve el problema